# How to change the text on ARcore Sample - Solar System

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I'm trying to add / change the text on the Solar System Augmented Reality sample from ARcore. For example Earth to No. 3 Earth, but I could not find anywhere to do this.

I tried changing the name in Earth.sfb in the Assets folder, but it doesn't work.

```
model: {
    attributes: [ 
        'Position',
        'TexCoord',
        'Orientation',
    ],
    collision: {},
    file: 'sampledata/models/Earth/Earth.gltf',
    name: 'No.3-The Earth', 
    recenter: true, 
    scale: 0.5
```

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: model: {
    attributes: [
      'Position',
      'TexCoord',
      'Orientation',
    ],
    collision: {},
    file: 'sampledata/models/Earth/Earth.gltf',
    name: 'No.3-The Earth',
    recenter: true,
    scale: 0.5,